# Horizontal Scrollview to Swipe through coredata objects

Tags: core-data, uiscrollview, uikit, detailsview, uipagecontrol

I have an iOS app built on CoreData with tableviews and detailviews of the objects.

When in the detailview I would like to swipe horizontally to get the detail view of the next object.

I found PageControl and scrollview. But this is going to be for over 100 objects in the model.

Does anyone have a good sample of this or resource on how to do this.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: have you found a good solution? i am searching for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could make individual views for each Core Data Object, then place those views on a UIScrollView.

You would need to set the contentSize:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * allYourViews.count, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Then loop over all your views and add them to the scrollView:

```
for(int i = 0; i < allYourViews.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;

    if(allYourViews.count > 0) {
        UIView* someView = (UIView *)allYourViews[i];
        someView.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:someView];
    }
}
```

For more information and how to make it scroll nicely, check this tutorial:

http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

( I don't know how this will perform :-)